# Flowgorithm: importing variables and modifying their values

Tags: import, module, flowgorithm

My professor likes work to be turned in in Flowgorithm.

I can't figure out how to take the variable `X=0` from the `main` method to the `displayLoop` method and then allow the `displayLoop` method to modify the stored value so it can be used as a countdown (or countup in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Flowgorithm, like Java, uses pass-by-value for types like Integer, Real, etc...

To return one less, you can create a function and return the decremented value. So, maybe try something like this:

```
count = displayLoop(count)
```

The assignment sounds a tad strange. Is this a recursion assignment?